# pandas how to check if the following 2 rows have the same column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2], [9,0],[3,4], [3,4]], columns=list('AB'))
```

output:

```
    A   B
0   1   2
1   9   0
2   3   4
3   3   4
```

The length of the df is always even. I need to divide the rows by 2 ,it means ,first row compare with second row ,third row compare with forth row ,...,n-1 row compare with n row.
My question is how to check if the column values of each 2 rows is exact the same.

For example, the first row and the second row are not the same ,but the third row and forth row are the same.

Comment: What would the output look like? Have a look at pd.DataFrame.shift: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html

you might do something like `df.shift().eq(df).all(axis=1)`

Answer (score 1):

Do you want:

```
df.iloc[::2].eq(df.iloc[1::2].values)
```

Output:

```
       A      B
0  False  False   # first row (index=0) vs second (index=1)
2   True   True   # third row (index=2) vs fourth (index=3)
```

To test equality of all columns:

```
df.iloc[::2].eq(df.iloc[1::2].values).all(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
0    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['pairs'] = df.index // 2
(df.groupby('pairs').apply('nunique') == 1).apply(all, axis=1)
```

Comment: This is solution looks easily understand ,but I received an error :TypeError: 'str' object is not callable